# Another website has lower pagerank (4) and lower backlinks, but they score higher than me in search results

Tags: seo

My website has a pagerank of 6 but it ranks poorly (6th position), they have the 3rd position despite a lower pagerank. The sites are about the same subject. I have title text on links, content is not flash, etc. Why?

Comment: PageRank is for web *pages*, not web *sites*. Are you talking about the PR of each site's home page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're making the common mistake of confusing PageRank (the Google algorithm score) with Ranking. While PR is a ranking factor, it's only one of 200+ (some say 1000+) elements that make up for your final page ranking.

And remember, localization, personalization and relevancy to that query all factor greatly in results.

You might rank #1 for a different keyword/phrase, or not at all.

Short Answer: PageRank has little to do with results rank.

Comment: Additionally, PR could still be an important ranking factor but the PR numbers you are seeing could be outdated, as Google sometimes only updates publicly available PR a couple times a year but probably uses a more frequently updated number for their calculations.

Answer (score -1):

Page rank is important as per weighing a website's overall importance, but seach engines view sites differently through query relevancy, content, how often the site is indexed, inbound links, etc.

Comment: PageRank is **not** for weighing a website's overall importance. It is only a numerical representation of a *single web page's* link popularity.